# Multiple the contents of the Nodes Linked List

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I have a programming challenge that is to recursively multiple the data in the nodes of the list  following it. For example

> 2 - 4 - 6 - 8

will be

> 384 - 192- 48 - 8

This is what I have done so far in the void product method. I keep getting a null pointer exception. What is wrong with my product method

```
 class Node
      {
        private int data;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;
        public Node(int newData,Node newNext,Node newPrev)
        {
          data = newData;
          next = newNext;
          prev = newPrev;
        }
        public int getData() 
        { 
          return data; 
        }

        public void setData(int otherData)
        {
          this.data = otherData;
        }
        public Node getNext() 
        { 
          return next; 
        }
        public Node getPrev() 
        { return prev; 
        }
        public void setNext(Node newNext)
        {   
          next = newNext; 
        }
        public void setPrev(Node newPrev)
        {
          prev = newPrev;
        }
      }


    class LinkedList
      {
        private Node head;
        private Node start;
        private Node end;
        public LinkedList()
        { 
          head = null; 
          start = null;
          end = null;
        }

        public void insert(int data)
        {
          Node newNode = new Node(data,null,null);

          if(start == null)
          {
            start = newNode;
            end = start;
          }
          else
          {
            newNode.setPrev(end);
            end.setNext(newNode);
            end = newNode;
          }
        }

        public void product()
        {
          product(head);   
        }
        public void product(Node head)
        {
          Node next = head.getNext();
          if(head == null)
          {
            return;
          }
          else
          {
            int data = head.getData() * next.getData();
            head.setData(data);
            product(head.getNext());
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `96` be `192` (as in 4 * 6 * 8)?

Comment: Yeap. Thank you for the correction

Comment: Yet another NullPointerException question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `head.getNext()` and `next.getData()` without checking if either of `head` or `next` is null, so the program will crash when processing the last node. Even so, you are only multiplying two consecutive items and not accumulating the product.

You can make use of the function's return value to accumulate the right answer:

```
    public void product()
    {
      product(head);   
    }
    public int product(Node head)
    {
      if(head == null)
      {
        return 1;
      }
      else
      {
        int data = head.getData() * product(head.getNext());
        head.setData(data);
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>I didn't check the *logic* of your **entire** code</sub>, but the first thing that comes to mind is that you assign:

`Node next = head.getNext();`

And then you check `if(head == null)` but what about `if(next == null)`?
If it is, then you have your error right here:

`next.getData()`

Because `head` can be non-`null`, but its `next` can certainly be `null`.

---

The **correct** course of action would be to first check `if(head == null)`, then assign `Node next = head.getNext();`, and *then* check `if(next == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you call `getNext()` method on `head` and *then* you check if `head` is `null`? That is clearly wrong.

You should first check if `head` is `null`. Then you should check if `next` is `null`.

Also I don't think your recursion will compute the product correctly, since you multiply the data in your `current` head with what's currently in `next` - you could achieve that with a simple loop.

Instead you should call `product(next)` *first* and compute product *later*. Like this (didn't test it though)

```
public void product(Node head)
{  
  if (head == null)
    return;
  Node next = head.getNext();   
  product(next);
  if (next != null)
  {
    int data = head.getData() * next.getData();
    head.setData(data);
  }
}
```